# Exclude method invocation from performance measurement

Tags: java, performance, jmh

I'm trying to write a benchmark in `JMH` to measure a performance of our customized collection.

I mean the performance of putting an object into it. The thing is on each iteration I want to generate an object to put, but I want to exclude the generation from the benchmark result itself.

Here is how it would look like:

```
@Benchmark
public void m(){
    Collection<Object> c = create();
    Object o = createObject();
    // I want to measure performance of the following line only
    c.add(o);
}

public Collection<Object> create(){
    //return the instance of the collection
}

public Object createObject(){
    //return some object
}
```

I know about the `@Setup` annotation, but it is only invoked when benchmark is started. So its not exactly what I want.

Comment: What about using StopWatch?

Comment: @Perimosh What about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create those objects within a setup method, and for example store them in a pre-built array.

Then providing new objects boils down to an array access and index increase operation. I am pretty sure that you will not find a way to do that with less effort.

In other words: if you do not want to benchmark object creation, then the only other alternative is to create them **upfront** and somehow remember them for later use. And if @Setup isn't what you are looking for; simply use some static array that gets filled when your class gets loaded.

Comment: I dont think `@Setup` works here. Because I need to create new objects on each method invokation.